# I want to write a notification button for fragment, but i have a some problems with code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to write a notification button for fragment, but i have a some problems with code. I didn’t work much with fragments, mainly activities. I think there are certain spelling differences that I cannot find.

```
class NotificationsFragment : Fragment()
{

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttons_notifications, container, false)

        val button: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.notification_btn)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(requireContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mount5)
                .setContentTitle("123")
                .setContentText("456")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(requireContext()))
            {
                notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
            }
        }
```

```
} <--- i have error here
```

```
    companion object
    {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 101
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "channelID"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add `return root` before closing `onCreateView` like this:

```kotlin
class NotificationsFragment : Fragment()
{

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttons_notifications, container, false)

        val button: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.notification_btn)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(requireContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mount5)
                    .setContentTitle("123")
                    .setContentText("456")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(requireContext()))
            {
                notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
            }
        }
        return root
    } //<--- you have error here
    companion object
    {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 101
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "channelID"
    }
}
```